# Find $f(x)$ given integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials

$f$ is a polynomal of a degree of $2$ **or less** and I know that:

$$\int_{-5}^{3} f(x) dx = \int_{6}^{8} f(x) dx = \int_{9}^{11} f(x) dx = 0$$

I need to find $f(x)$ using the mean value theorem.

I know from the mean value theorem that there exist $c_{1}, c_{2}, c_{3}$ such that:

$$8\cdot f(c_{1}) = 2\cdot f(c_{2}) = 2\cdot f(c_{3}) = 0$$

But now what? What is the way to find the function?

Comment: @RoryDaulton. Sorry for having interfered ! You are right. The OP needs to find it. I suggest you delete your comment too. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I'm sorry if I miscommunicated. I do not think that you "interfered," but I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @RoryDaulton. You did not miscommunicate at all, be sure. As a stupid, I  "interfered" ! I am sure that you are a good professor. I really enjoy when I see answers from you. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are $8f(c_1)$, $2f(c_2)$, and $2f(c_3)$ all equal to? Also, where do $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$ live?

Comment: to zero... so i think $f(x) = 0$ but what is the explanation for that? maybe i could find another function that fits

Comment: So what do you conclude if a polynomial of degree at most 2 has 3 roots?

Comment: Oh it can't have these 3 roots unless $f$ is constant and equals 0?

Comment: Correct. :) $\quad$

Comment: But wait... I only know that $4f(c_{1}) = f(c_{2}) = f(c_{3}) = 0$ so maybe it has 2 roots ($c_{2}$ and $c_{3}$)?

Comment: That's why I asked you where the $c$'s live.

Comment: Oh but if $4f(c_{1}) = 0$ then $f(c_{1}) = 0$ as well. Alright I get it now! Thanks (:

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer when you are satisfied so that the question doesn't continue to appear unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

**(This answer was given before an important requirement was added to the question.)**

Ignore the mean value theorem, since it does not tell you the value of the constant.

Since you know $f$ is a polynomial of degree 2 or less, just set

$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$

From that you can find the values of the three integrals as expressions in $a$, $b$, and $c$. Then solve for $a$, $b$, and $c$ from your given equations.

Ask if you need help in continuing from there.

Comment: This take a lot of time and I have been instructed to use the mean value theorem... What is another approach to this question?

Comment: I am sorry! I missed an important part of the question! I edited my question. Very sorry...

Comment: @Lisa: I have added that requirement to your question.  From now on, please be careful to include *all* relevant information to your question.